# ServiceFabric communication with local WPF App

Tags: c#, wpf, azure-service-fabric

Is there any way to connect Service Fabric Stateless service (in local) to my local WPF app? I would like to process some data on stateless service and send update to WPF app for example using NServiceBus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use a message queue for this.

Your stateless service would create a message and put it on the queue:

```cs
    static async Task SendMessageAsync()
    {
        // create a Service Bus client 
        await using (ServiceBusClient client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString))
        {
            // create a sender for the queue 
            ServiceBusSender sender = client.CreateSender(queueName);

            // create a message that we can send
            ServiceBusMessage message = new ServiceBusMessage("Hello world!");

            // send the message
            await sender.SendMessageAsync(message);
            Console.WriteLine($"Sent a single message to the queue: {queueName}");
        }
    }
```

The WPF application would receive that message and process it:

```cs
    // handle received messages
    static async Task MessageHandler(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)
    {
        string body = args.Message.Body.ToString();
        // update the ViewModel here

        // complete the message. messages is deleted from the queue. 
        await args.CompleteMessageAsync(args.Message);
    }
```

Instead of sending a simple string, I recommend sending a serialized object, e.g. using JSON.

More info here:
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues)
and here:
[link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/samples)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot! 